# Awesome CV template: how to add two phone numbers

Tags: awesome-cv

I've been use this template for almost 2 years and it is just really beautiful and versatile.

Can somebody tell me how to add two phone numbers? I tried:

```
\mobile{US +1 (111) 111-1111} 
\mobile{IT +39 (111) 1111111}
```

but this, as expected, gives me just the second phone number. How can I have both with the same icon displayed (i.e. they're both mobile)?

Thanks,
Eleonora

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue a few months ago, tried a few things but did not manage to get it. I settled for a ***workaround***. Instead of having two mobile phone icons I added both numbers in the `\mobile{}` field and added a small flag in front of them (.svg flags of all states can be found on [WikimediaCommons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Sovereign-state_flags)). A few spaces and `raisebox`es were needed to get the desired output.

Code:

```
\mobile{\ \raisebox{-0.5pt}{\includesvg[height=6pt]{Flag_of_the_United_States}}\ (+1) 234-5678 %
\ \raisebox{-0.5pt}{\includesvg[height=6pt]{Flag_of_Italy}} \ (+39) 23456789}
```

Output:
[image: Dual phone numbers awesome CV]

The same thing can be applied to the email address if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really good idea! I’m going to use this! Thank you so much!